# Como faço para arredondar números para o inteiro mais próximo?

Tags: c#, .net, matemática, arredondamento

Tenho números `double` como

```
double a = 0.4, b = 0.5;
```

Como faço para arredondar?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Para um arredondamento simples use o método [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que recebe um double (ou decimal) e arredonda pro inteiro mais próximo:

```
Math.Round(0.4); // 0
Math.Round(0.6); // 1
```

Entretanto, esse método tem um porém: se o número a ser arredondado está na metade do caminho entre um inteiro e outro (ex.: `0.5`) ele sempre arredondará para o número **par**:

```
Math.Round(1.5); // 2
Math.Round(2.5); // 2
```

Para se ter maior controle sobre o resultado, use o [método sobrecarregado](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (*overloaded*) que aceita o parâmetro adicional [`MidpointRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Ele é uma enumeração, que aceita os seguintes valores:

- `AwayFromZero` (escolhe o inteiro mais "distante" do zero, ou seja: o maior, se o parâmetro for positivo, o menor se ele for negativo)
- `ToEven` (escolhe o inteiro par, semelhante ao comportamento padrão)

Note que existem casos em que as opções acima não são suficientes: se você deseja que o número seja arredondado **na direção do zero** (i.e. o inteiro com o menor **valor absoluto**), e seus parâmetros podem incluir números negativos, mais de uma operação pode ser necessária. Um exemplo seria:

```
public double PontoMedioDirecaoZero(double d) {
    double absInt = Math.Floor(Math.Abs(d)); // Piso do valor absoluto
    double absDec = Math.Round(Math.Abs(d) - absInt); // Arredondamento do valor absoluto
    return Math.Sign(d) * (absInt + absDec); // "Monta" o resultado final
}
PontoMedioDirecaoZero(-1.5); // -1
```

Uma estratégia semelhante pode ser necessária caso se deseje arredondar **sempre** (e não só no ponto médio) **para baixo** ([`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx)) ou **para cima** ([`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx)), levando em consideração o valor absoluto:

```
Math.Floor(0.6); // 0
Math.Floor(-0.6); // -1
Math.Sign(-0.6) * Math.Floor(Math.Abs(-0.6)); // 0
```

Comment: O correto é `Math.Ceiling(0.5);` para arredondamento para cima

Comment: @GuilhermeAlmeida Corrigi a resposta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

A [classe estática `Math`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contém métodos para arredondar números:

Use [`Math.Ceil`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx) para arredondar para cima

```
Math.Ceil(0.5); // 1
```

Use [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx) para arredondar, neste método você pode informar um segundo parâmetro para determinar se `0.5` arredonda para `1` ou `0`.

```
Math.Round(0.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // 1
Math.Round(0.5);                                // 0
```

Use [`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx) para arredondar para baixo

```
Math.Floor(0.5); // 0
```

Note que o retorno dos métodos são `double`, caso você tente converter um número muito grande para `int` você vai receber um `OverflowException`.

Comment: O correto é `Math.Ceiling(0.5);` para arredondamento para cima

Answer (score 2):

Eu tive esse problema e nenhuma das sugestões que pesquisei deram resultado.

Precisava arredondar **43,2549** igual ao Excel que dá o resultado **43,26**. O C# me retornava **43,25** sempre.

então fiz o seguinte:

```
   decimal resultado = Math.Round(43.2549, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Em seguida:

```
resultado = Math.Round(resultado, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Não ficou elegante, mas funcionou.